# Using Redux and Next.js and getting "store.getState is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next-redux-wrapper

I've set up my _app.js and store.js in what seems to be the expected format. This is my first attempt as using both so if I'm missing something obvious, please let me know.

store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import authReducer from '../store/slices/authSlice';
import searchReducer from '../store/slices/searchSlice';

const makeStore = () => {
    console.log('config store: ', configureStore({ reducer: { auth, search } }));
    return configureStore({
      reducer: {
        auth: authReducer,
        search: searchReducer,
      },
    });
}

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore, { debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' });
```

_app.js:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { wrapper } from '../store/store';
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  console.log('wrapper: ', wrapper);
  return (
    <Provider store={wrapper}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

The console.log of my wrapper is:

```
wrapper:  {
  getServerSideProps: [Function: getServerSideProps],
  getStaticProps: [Function: getStaticProps],
  getInitialAppProps: [Function: getInitialAppProps],
  getInitialPageProps: [Function: getInitialPageProps],
  withRedux: [Function: withRedux],
  useWrappedStore: [Function: useWrappedStore]
}
```

The reason I've done all this is because I was originally getting a legacy error when using withRedux so it said I had to use the createWrapper option.

I've tried to look up on here and on ChatGPT and Gemini and nothing seems to explain why I'm getting TypeError: store.getState is not a function. It also looks like makeStore is never getting called because the console.log in the function never logs.

Comment: The first line of makeStore function. you have `auth` and `search` and I am pretty sure you meant `authReducer` and `searchReducer` is that a typo in this question or your code?

Answer (score 1):

The `wrapper` returns functionality that you need to use first before you can access the store. You are passing `wrapper` directly as the `store`.

See [wrapper usage](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper?tab=readme-ov-file#usage).

- Using the `useWrappedStore` hook:

  ```
  import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
  import { wrapper } from '../store/store';

  function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const { store, props } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(pageProps);

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }

  export default MyApp;
  ```
- Using the `withRedux` Higher Order Component:

  ```
  import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
  import { wrapper } from '../store/store';

  function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
  }

  export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
  ```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much. My app was working fine when I was using the wrapper.withRedux (along with some other changes I had) but I kept getting that annoying yellow error that said I was using legacy behavior so I wanted to use the createWrapper and use it correctly. The first option you gave me works perfectly and removes that annoying error!

Thank you so much for your help.